# PHP League\Csv what's faster: iterating using a foreach loop or the Reader::fetchOne(n)?

Tags: php, csv

Which is faster:

```
$csvReader = League\Csv\Reader::createFromPath($csvFile->getPathname());

// a)
foreach ($csvReader as $row) {
    $this->processRow($row);
}

// or b)
$rowIndex = 0;
while (true) {
    $row = $csvReader->fetchOne($rowIndex);

    if (!$row) {
        break;
    }

    $this->processRow($row);

    $rowIndex += 1;
}
```

I checked the source code for `League\Csv` and found, that the solution `a)` uses a forward reading iterator, while the solution `b)` uses php's `LimitIterator(Iterator())`. So the question really boils down to: how fast php's LimitIterator's offset setting is. If it iterates over the initial items to skip the internal iterator to the item required by the offset, then it's pretty obvious, that the solution `a)` is faster.

I'd prefer to use the solution `b)` because it gives me more control over the iteration (e.g. to skip the header row). But if the performance is so detrimental, then I'd use solution `a)` (and skip the header row manually).

I'm pretty sure solution `b)` is incredibly slower. I'd just like someone smarter than me confirm that, because I can't quite get from the source code how the `LimitIterator` rewinds to the offset, when a csv file is used.

Comment: So what benchmark have you made?

Comment: I haven't done any tbh. I'd rather know how it works internally instead of relying on benchmarks. But since you mentioned it, I can actually exercise this code against a 1 million row csv. Hold on a sec

Comment: Tested against 1k row csv. The difference is massive. Solution `a)` takes about 0.07s to finish, while solution `b)` takes about 6.75s to finish. This pretty much means, that using `LimitIterator` for anything substantial is just a no-go. Well, I guess I answered my own question then. Unless someone else has anything to add.

Comment: Micro-optimizations like this rarely have any significant impact on overall performance / capacity - but I note from your answer that it does have a very major impact here (!) this rather implies that there is a *lot* of scope for optimizing your file iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Solution `a)` is faster. For 1k row file, `a)` runs in 0.07s while `b)` runs in 6.75s

To manually skip the header in the solution `a)`, I did this:

```
$rowsIterator = $csvReader->getIterator();
$rowsIterator->current(); // I don't know why this is needed, but without this, it doesn't skip the header.
$rowsIterator->next();

while ($rowsIterator->valid()) {
    $this->processRow($rowsIterator->current());
    $rowsIterator->next();
}
```

For interested readers: The following ways didn't work or didn't satisfy me:

```
// c) foreach loop seems to be rewinding the iterator's pointer to the beginning at start
$rowsIterator = $csvReader->getIterator();
$rowsIterator->current();
$rowsIterator->next();

foreach ($rowsIterator as $row) {
    $this->processRow($row);
}

// d) `if` statement every iteration takes time
foreach ($csvReader as $rowIndex => $row) {
    if ($rowIndex === 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $this->processRow($row);
}

// e) LimitIterator is slower than my final solution for some reason
foreach (new LimitIterator($csvReader->getIterator(), 1) as $row) {
    $this->processRow($row);
}
```